# get line with question mark and line before that - sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

i have some text being piped to sed (any other tool is okay). I want to extract the line which ends with a question mark and the line before that. how can we achieve this?

eg text

```
& 434.0K
-

.... 
What are you trying to filter
out of screencap's output?
Student
xcvdgfdg
srrtgg
```

Comment: `grep -B1 '\?$'`

Comment: the one from Sean is a perfect answer to this. @SeanBright do you want to post an answer?

Comment: The output is not ideal. It spits out a `--` between the matches for context.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '/\?$/{print prev ORS $0} {prev=$0}'  Input_file
```

For your shown Input following will be the output.

```
What are you trying to filter
out of screencap's output?
```

on a Solaris/SunOS system, change `awk` to `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` , `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` , or `nawk`.

***Explanation of code:***

`/\?$/`: Searching for a line which is ending with `?` if yes then do following.

`{print prev ORS $0}`: Using `awk`'s print function here by which we are printing variable named `prev` and `$0`(current line)'s value here.

`{prev=$0}`: So Here I am storing the current line's value to variable named prev so that in case of a match of `?` at line's last, could print the previous line.

Comment: As i am trying to use this on pipe , i am running this `xargs -I {} -0  awk '/\?$/{print prev ORS $0} {prev=$0}' {}` but it throws `awk: fatal: cannot open file `& 434.0K`

Comment: @nithin, why are you using this with `xargs`? Please explain on it more?

Comment: I dont have the output in a file, i am piping it from  tesseract. whole command :  `tesseract sc.png stdout | sed '/^$/d' | xargs -I {} -0  awk '/\?$/{print prev ORS $0} {prev=$0}' {}`

Comment: @nithin, not understanding what is use of `xargs` here? try with single `awk` no after `sed` and let me know then?

Answer (score 1):

A sed solution:

```
sed -n '/?$/{x;G;p;};h'
```

Rough translation: in general, don't print anything. If this line ends with '$', prepend it with the line in the hold space and print it. And save this line in the hold space.

Comment: You beat me to it although mine is a bit different `sed -n 'H;/?$/{x;p};x'`. But they are practically the same that's why I am not posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` to match the line in question then use `-A num` for lines after or `-B num` for lines before the match.

Given:

```
$ echo "$txt"
& 434.0K
-

.... 
What are you trying to filter
out of screencap's output?
Student
xcvdgfdg
srrtgg
```

One line before:

```
$ echo "$txt" | grep -B1 '\?$'
What are you trying to filter
out of screencap's output?
```

One line after:

```
$ echo "$txt" | grep -A1 '\?$'
out of screencap's output?
Student
```

etc.

POSIX and GNU grep supported.

---

If you have multiple matches, `grep` will put `--` between each match:

```
$ echo "$txt$txt" | grep -A1 '\?$'
out of screencap's output?
Student
--
out of screencap's output?
Student
```

If that is a problem, pipe through `sed` to delete it:

```
$ echo "$txt$txt" | grep  -A1  '\?$' | sed  '/^--*$/d'
out of screencap's output?
Student
out of screencap's output?
Student
```

Answer (score 0):

Another sed solution

```
sed '$d;N;/?$/!D' infile
```

Comment: I'll upvote, because this is a solution that works without the holdspace, which is something I tried to find and failed. But why does it need the `$d`?

Comment: @Beta Without $d, the last line is always print.

Comment: Not in my experiments.